# Configure Symfony to use multiple mongodb databases

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

In my application i have to use two different MongoDb databses.
So i followed the instruction in the following  [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html).Here is a part of my app/config.yml file

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    default_database: music_store_database
    default_connection: conn1
    default_document_manager: dm1
    connections:
       conn1:
          server: mongodb://localhost:27017
          options:
             connect: true
             db: music_store_database
      conn2:
         server: mongodb://localhost:27017
         options:
            connect: true
            db: another_database
    document_managers:
        dm1:
            connection: conn1
            mappings:
                MyfirstBundle: ~
        dm2:
            connection: conn2
            mappings:
                MySecondBundle: ~
```

Now if i do an ./app/console cache:clear --env=prod or anything else i get this issue:

```
  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]                                                                  

  The service "doctrine_mongodb.odm.conn1_connection" has a dependency on a non-         existent service "doctrine_mongodb.odm.conn1_configuration".
  The service "doctrine_mongodb.odm.conn1_connection" has a dependency on a non-          existent service "doctrine_mongodb.odm.conn1_configuration".
```

I am stuck i didn't find any workaround.So i wonder what i am doing wrong? what is the right way to configure Symfony to use two MongoDb databases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to change **dm1** and **dm2** to **conn1** and **conn2**. I reproduced your problem and just with this small change I made it work.

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    default_database: music_store_database
    default_connection: conn1
    default_document_manager: conn1
    connections:
        conn1:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options:
                connect: true
                db: music_store_database
        conn2:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options:
                connect: true
                db: another_database
    document_managers:
        conn1:
            connection: conn1
            mappings:
                MyFirstBundle: ~
        conn2:
            connection: conn2
            mappings:
                MySecondBundle: ~
```